# How to get the time difference from multiple starttimes and endtime which are coming from a file?

Tags: powershell

I have file with below data, I want to get the highest time difference from this using PowerShell.

```
STARTTIME:2018-12-01 04:13:15

ENDTIME:2018-12-01 04:17:15

--
--
STARTTIME:2018-12-01 04:11:15

ENDTIME:2018-12-01 04:13:15

--

STARTTIME:2018-12-01 04:10:15

ENDTIME:2018-12-01 04:10:40
```

I expect the output to be 00:04:00

Comment: Can you please show us some code that you currently have and approaches your have tried?

Comment: Hi there,
I'd use New-timespan myself to check each one but so much of it depends on the file layout that its hard to wrap it all up in a script without seeing an example of your source data layout.
Try New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-date) -End (Get-date).AddDays( +1) to give you an idea.

Comment: If struggling to get the starttime and endtime from the file. But once I have the times I was using it like below.


Code:
$sdate="2015-12-01 04:13:15"
$edate="2015-12-01 04:14:16"
$dif= New-TimeSpan -Start $sdate -End $edate
Write-Host "Time difference is "$dif

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regular Expression to select lines and `STARTTIME`/`ENDTIME`
to set a variable with that name and the [datetime] value

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\15\SO_56150523.ps1

$FileIn = '.\times.txt'
$RE = [regex]'^(STARTTIME|ENDTIME):(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'

$Data = (Get-Content $FileIn)| Where-Object {$_ -match $RE}| ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name $Matches[1] -Value (Get-Date $Matches[2])
    if ($Matches[1] -eq 'ENDTIME'){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            StartTime = $StartTime
            EndTime   = $EndTime
            Duration  = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime
        }
    }
}
$Data

"`nThe longest duration is {0}" -f ($Data|Sort-Object Duration -Descending)[0].Duration
```

Sample output based on the complete text from question in file `times.txt`

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\15\SO_56150523.ps1

StartTime           EndTime             Duration
---------           -------             --------
2018-12-01 04:13:15 2018-12-01 04:17:15 00:04:00
2018-12-01 04:11:15 2018-12-01 04:13:15 00:02:00
2018-12-01 04:10:15 2018-12-01 04:10:40 00:00:25

The longest duration is 00:04:00
```

Comment: Thanks LotPings !!

Comment: If answers solve your question or you find them helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)(requires [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) >= 15 to take effect)